# What decides the response time parameter requirement for zener diode

Tags: zener, circuit-protection, surge-protection, diode-clamp

Assuming that a zener diode is being used to prevent over voltage condition from destroying an electronic component; how does the designer know what range of response time is required when choosing the zener?

Comment: I would Imagine that the engineer would take the integral of wattage with respect to time to get energy, and set that below a threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Most protection circuits are based upon the energy that is needed to be absorbed and there is no explicit time associated with that.  That is because one is normally designing to protect against ESD transients.

If you know that you are going to have a sustained fault condition then you must design for it as most protection circuits with sustained fault will overheat and fail.

That means that a sustained fault condition is now part of the specification and thus must undergo a full design approach. i.e It must be designed for.